# Do all Blackberry 10 cascades apps include Core APIs as well?

Tags: mobile, blackberry, blackberry-10, cascade

So far I know that BlackBerry 10 has two main kind of apps.

> `1) Cascade apps 2) Core Native apps`

I need to know whether all cascaded apps have the support for core native APIs as well. And also if a core native app is made, does it have access to the cascade framweork? For example does a core native app have access to Signals and slots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cascades applications can access core native APIs quite easily thought the message passing method is different. Cascades uses the Qt signal/slot method, core native applications use a queue/polling method.

To take advantage of signals and slots you would have to implement either pure Qt or Cascades objects, so it would no longer really be just core native applications. Thoug that is just semantics. That said there is support for most core functionality in Cascades. When support is not available I generally write the queue code into the processing object for a QtThread and change queue events into signals.